# Probability of having a given value, if the variable changes every fixed period?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have to solve the following problem, which is finding the probability of having a given value. My data is as follows:

- I have `N` conditions in the environment. Each of them, can equally be 0 or 1 (discrete values only)
- After `t` time, a fixed amount of my `N` conditions (`s`) changes its value. This "refresh" happens again after `t+t`, and again at `t+t+t`, and so on. This keeps happening during an indefinite amount of time.

My problem is: suppose that I need `N1 = 0`. What is the probability of that equality being true, at a given time? Even if change happens at every `t` time, my variable `N1` may not be "chosen" to change (if that makes any sense?).

I do think this is a uniform distribution (because it can take the values 0 or 1 with equal chance). But I don't know how to incorporate the other values in my equation.

Comment: Note that this seems equivalent to asking: condition N1 is the only variable, and the probability that it changes at each multiple of $t$ equals $S/N$. What exact question are you asking when you talk about the probability of the values of N1? Is the initial state of N1 fixed or random? If it's fixed, the probability depends on the number of time intervals, so which time interval are you asking about?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question... I'm really rusty with probability. The initial state of `N1` is random (either 0 or 1, and I don't know which). If I have `N` variables, `S` randomly selected variables change at intervals `t`. So, the variable I am considering for the example (`N1`, I always consider a single variable) may be selected to change or not (if it is not selected, it doesn't change its value, otherwise, it flips between 0 and 1).

Comment: Is the initial condition of your variable 0 or 1?

Comment: @tomi I don't know. It can be either, with the same chance of being 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be handled as a recurrence relationship. *(It can also be treated as a Markov Chain problem.)*

Your variable has two possible states: being 0 or being 1.

Let $x_k=P(N_1=0$ after $k$ steps$)$

and $y_k=P(N_1=1$ after $k$ steps$)$

These are mutually exclusive, so $x_k+y_k=1$

$x_0$ and $y_0$ will depend on the initial condition (hence my question in the comments).

If you start with $N_1=0$, then $x_0=1$ and $y_0=0$

If you start with $N_1=1$, then $x_0=0$ and $y_0=1$

If the initial value of $N_1$ is a random choice, with equal chance of either state, then $x_0=0.5$ and $y_0=0.5$

Now let's consider the change from the $k$th step to the $k+1$th step.

If all variables are equally likely to be changed, then your variable $N_1$ has a probability $p=\frac s N$ of changing at each step. The probability of no change is $1-p$.

$P(N_1=0$ after $k+1$ steps$)=P(N_1=0$ after $k$ steps$) \times P($there is no change $) + P(N-1=1$ after $k$ steps$) \times P($there is a change$)$

This is equivalent to $x_{k+1}=(1-p)x_k+py_k$

Substitute $y_k=1-x_k$ to get $x_{k+1}=(1-p)x_k+p(1-x_k)$

$x_{k+1}=x_k-px_k+p-px_k$

$x_{k+1}=p+(1-2p)x_k$

It is well established that a recurremce relationship of this form can be solved t0 give:

$x_k=A+B(1-2p)^k$

Setting $k=0 \Rightarrow x_0=A+B$

Setting $k=1 \Rightarrow x_1=A +B(1-2p)$

We know that $x_{k+1}=p+(1-2p)x_k \Rightarrow x_1=p+(1-2p)x_0$

so $A +B(1-2p)=p+(1-2p)x_0$

Use $A=x_0-B$ to get $x_0-B +B(1-2p)=p+(1-2p)x_0 \Rightarrow -2pB=p-2px_0 \Rightarrow B=x_0-\frac 1 2$

Then $A=x_0-B=x_0-x_0+\frac 1 2=\frac 1 2$

So $x_k=\frac 1 2+(x_0-\frac 1 2)(1-2p)^k$

Provided $0<p<1$ we will have $0<(1-2p)<1$ which means that $x_k \rightarrow \frac 1 2$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

If we in fact have $x_0=\frac 1 2$ then $(1-2p)=0$ and we have $x_k=\frac 1 2$ for all $k$.

Comment: Hello. Thanks! I was following up the answer quite well, until "It is a well established recurrence...". Can you simplify the explanation after that, please?

Comment: @Mel This result is pretty standard for a non-homogeneous first order recurrence relationship - which is what we have here. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) is quite dense on this topic, so this from MEI (https://mei.org.uk/files/conference19/I2.pdf) might be a gentler introduction.